# How to link Touch ID with login credentials?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keychain, touch-id

I'm able to validate a user Touch ID successfully. However, what's the safest way to retrieve the user login and password to perform login once the touch ID authentication is successful.

For iTunes connect app, once the touch ID login is successful, seems like it will retrieve the password locally and fill it in the password UITextField. I'm guessing it's using keychain.

However is it safe to store user credentials on the iPhone itself? Are there any other methods?

[image]

Comment: You can use touchID to provide authenticated access to the KeyChain - refer to the Apple sample code.  The KeyChain provides secure storage for passwords.

Comment: Thx @Paulw11 Is it really secure to store user credentials in keychain? I'm building an app with highly sensitive data. Recently the customer wants to integrate the touch id function.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will be able to build a more secure container than KeyChain provides - This white paper provides some background on how the Keychain works - http://images.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide_Oct_2014.pdf

Comment: You can restrict access to your app using both the device's pass code or a custom password unique to your app, and in both cases you can let the user authenticate with Touch ID instead of providing the actual password/pass code.

Comment: DropBox.app uses the former approach, 1Password.app uses the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to store the login information in the keychain, but you need to make sure that the accessibility parameter is set to kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked or kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly (kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly is a bit safer since the password will not leave the device, say when the device is backed up to your laptop.)

```
NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[query setObject:(id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(id)kSecClass];
[query setObject:account forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[query setObject:(id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccessible];
[query setObject:[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:(id)kSecValueData];

OSStatus error = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)query, NULL);
```

(Code is from http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad/